# Question about proof of triangle inequality in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

I am having some trouble with one inequality used in the proof of the triangle inequality in $\mathbb{C}$. The main issue is realizing that for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$, we have that $2 \cdot Re(z\overline{w}) \leq 2 \cdot |z \overline{w} |$. This fact has been exploited in the proof I am currently reading as well as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582433/prove-the-triangle-inequality-involving-complex-numbers) and also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279565/triangle-inequality-with-complex-numbers). However if we take $z = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}i$ and $w = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}i$, then it follows that $z \overline{w} = (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3}i)(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{5}i) = \frac{23}{120} - \frac{1}{60}i$ and so $2 \cdot Re(z \overline{w}) = \frac{23}{60}$ and $2 \cdot |z \overline{w}| = \frac{533}{7200}$ and so $2 \cdot Re(z \overline{w}) \geq 2 \cdot |z \overline{w}|$... So my question is am I merely making a mistake somewhere or are there some restrictions on which complex numbers this inequality applies to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have made an error computing $|\overline{z}w|$: $\frac{533}{7200}$ is $2|\overline{z}w|^2$, not $2|\overline{z}w|$.  When you remember to take the square root, you get $2|\overline{z}w|=\frac{\sqrt{533}}{60}$, which is indeed slightly larger than $\frac{23}{60}$.

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake. Is there an easy proof of this fact then?

Comment: It's pretty trivial by just plugging in the definitions: for any $z=x+iy$, $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\geq\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=|\operatorname{Re} z|$.

Comment: Duh. Not enough sleep. Thanks for the help.